# What directory path to set in geoserver for Neo4j data source?

Tags: neo4j, spatial, geoserver

I have installed neo4j spatial in my Geoserver2.6 and now I am trying to see an example of a database.
I created in geoserver a workspace and then I want to add a new store. I select the neo4j store but then I don't know what to put in the field "Connection Parameters" (The directory path of the Neo4j database).
Till now I was using postgis, which you add the host name and the port.
What should I put in this field?
Any help will be mostly appreciated.
Thanks
D.

**EDIT:**
I found out that the directory path must have this form:
     file:C:/Program Files/NEO4J_HOME/neo4j-community-1.9.9/data/graph.db/neostore.id

The path points to the neostore.id file inside the database. 
The problem remains. Nothing happens when I select the save button in geoserver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original wiki that contained the answer to this was shut down a while back. But there is a copy at http://oss.infoscience.co.jp/neo4j/wiki.neo4j.org/content/Neo4j_Spatial_in_GeoServer.html. This is old information, but should still contain the answer you are looking for.

Comment: Hi Craig. Thanks for the answer. I have found this site and used the instructions but I didn't manage to make it work. First I tried to point to the neostore.id file of a neo4j database I have created. But it didn't work (I just click the "save" button in geoserver and nothing happens - firebug show me some post request failure). The I tried to use the database created during the unit tests of neo4j spatial (with maven). But I can not find the db files cause as long as the tests run then the files are deleted. Do you have some idea how to change this?

Comment: Actually do you know if there is activity on neo4j spatial with geoserver and uDig? I see that the documentation online is very poor and outdated (since 2011) and I haven't found someone that actually used geoserver with neo4j successfully.